# Codeigniter setting that doesn't allow get or post form submissions?

Tags: php, codeigniter, frameworks

I'm working in a CI(1.7.2) environment where I have a routes, hooks, ssl and https configuration on certain pages.

My problem is that I can pass hidden form fields from one view to another controller (via post or get), but no dynamic form variables (text or textarea inputs). Looking at firebug NET, I get a 500 error message.

The URL passes, but with blank variables:

```
pages/request?req_email=&req_about=
```

I've built several CI environments before, but none with special routing or hooks. Any ideas about a setting that could be causing these not to pass?

Comment: Can you post a bit more information about your "dynamic form variables"?

Comment: What relation have continuous-integration with this question? Maybe you want to set to codeigniter instead of this?

Comment: Sergio - you're right - I meant to tag with CodeIgniter. Thanks

Comment: Are you using CRSF protection in your config file but not using the CRSF hidden field in your form fields? Try building your form with the form_open() function and you will find out. Or check: http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/security.html. I'm not sure if this could cause this behavior, but it's probably worth checking it.

Comment: stefandoom - that got it! Thanks:)

Answer (score 0):

i dont know about 1.7.2, but as of 2.0 enabling query string in your config file will cause other helpers not to work... i would assume two of those helpers would be URI and FILE helpers..  but that may give you a direction to start looking in.